# Create columns for sub-strings in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table of URL hosts with a varying number of dots, e.g. "sub.domain.co.uk", "domain.co.uk" and "domain.com" in one column, and the parts of each host (split up at dots) in the second column. Example of data:

```
CREATE TABLE dt AS 
SELECT * FROM
(WITH temp AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'domain', 1), ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'co', 2), ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'uk', 3), ('domain.co.uk', 'co', 1), ('domain.co.uk', 'uk', 2), ('domain.com', 'com', 1)) AS account (host, part, n)
)
SELECT host, part, n from temp)
```

[image]

Ultimately, I want to create a column that creates subsets of the `host` field, the first combining the second to `n`th part until the last containing just the `n`th part. Desired output with example data:

```
WITH dt AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'domain', 1, 'domain.co.uk'), ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'co', 2, 'co.uk'), ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'uk', 3, 'uk'), ('domain.co.uk', 'co', 1, 'co.uk'), ('domain.co.uk', 'uk', 2, 'uk'), ('domain.com', 'com', 1, 'com')) AS account (host, part, number, subset)
)
SELECT host, part, number, subset from dt;
```

[image]

I have found a solution with window function. The only problem is that since the number of parts for each `host` varies in my real data, I have to first find the maximum number of parts, and then create the according number of window-function columns, and then concatenate the columns. So with maximum number of 4 parts:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE 
  WHEN part_2 IS NULL THEN part
  WHEN part_2 IS NOT NULL AND part_3 IS NULL THEN concat(part, '.', part_2)
  WHEN part_3 IS NOT NULL THEN concat(part, '.', part_2, '.', part_3)
  END AS pattern
  FROM
(SELECT 
    host, part,
    LEAD(part) OVER (PARTITION BY host ORDER BY n_row) AS part_2,
    LEAD(part, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY host ORDER BY n_row) AS part_3
    FROM  
    (SELECT host, part, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY host) n_row
      FROM dt))
```

However, this gets annoying when the maximum number of parts gets higher. Is there any way to take care of this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

TBH I'm not sure what the end goal is here, but assuming that the requirement is just to get everything after the `part` starting from it you can just use `substring`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(host, part, n) AS (
    VALUES ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'domain', 1),
        ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'co', 2),
        ('sub.domain.co.uk', 'uk', 3),
        ('domain.co.uk', 'co', 1),
        ('domain.co.uk', 'uk', 2),
        ('domain.com', 'com', 1)
)

-- query
select host, part, try(substring(host, strpos(host, part)))
from dataset;
```

Output:

| host | part | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sub.domain.co.uk | domain | domain.co.uk |
| sub.domain.co.uk | co | co.uk |
| sub.domain.co.uk | uk | uk |
| domain.co.uk | co | co.uk |
| domain.co.uk | uk | uk |
| domain.com | com | com |

Answer (score 0):

If you have hosts like **comedycentral.com** or **petco.com.co** where the part can appear in multiple places, I think `arrays` would be easier to deal with, and more reliable as well.

In Presto, the [**split**](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html) function can take another parameter (*limit*) that allows one to split only first N elements and leave the rest intact as the last element. That last element can be made to be the substring you're looking to extract by defining *limit* parameter as N+1

```
select host, 
       part, 
       element_at(split(host,'.',n+1),-1) as extracted --cast to varchar if needed
from dataset;
```